# MongoDB distinct query on MongoLab

Tags: json, mongodb, distinct, mlab

I have database XXX and collection YYY in MongoDB (using MongoLab).

Here is a sample record:

```
{
 "_id": {
    "$oid": "551a5asdfsdfsdfs"
 },
 "_class": "com.test.com",
 "mvid": "d0fffsdfs"

}
```

I would like to retrieve all distinct values of the field "mvid". Here is what I write in search box

```
XXX.YYY.distinct("mvid")
```

I get back the following error:

"We encountered an error while parsing your JSON. Please check your syntax   (e.g. ensure you are using double quotes around both your field names and values) and try again."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the search box you mention part of your application?

Comment: I think you should try this `db.YYY.distinct("mvid")`

Comment: @yogesh, thank you, this is exactly what help page suggests, but it does not work.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, thank you, MongoLab is like web based studio for MongoDB. Search box is a text box area on MongoLab page, which allows you to enter queries. Sorry, I am new to MongoLab and MongoDB

Comment: @user1700890 From the screen shots I see on the MongoLab site, you can only use that search box for entering query objects, not shell commands like you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, JohnnyHK [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5UG5I_2qHRrN3MxeS1BRExKMDA/view?usp=sharing). I meant box called "Query", please see image attached.

Comment: @user1700890 Right, that box is for `find` query objects, not shell commands.

Comment: You are the man JohnnyHK! So I should use "Query" text box only for "find" command, for anything else I should use shell? You should post it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Query box on MongoLab is for entering JSON `find` query objects like:

```
{ "_class": "com.test.com" }
```

To run commands besides `find` like you're trying to do with your `distinct` command, you need to use the MongoDB shell or (if the command is directly supported) select the command under Tools / Commands in the MongoLab UI.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do something similar and the accepted answer is not actually correct.

You can actually run the following database and collection level commands directly through the mLab Data API. You just send the command via POST as per the documentation at the end of the page at https://docs.mlab.com/data-api/

Just out of interest you can additionally use commands like $exists within the query too as long as you get the syntax correct.

This enables much more power than most people (including myself) realize when reading these threads.

Available commands:

-getLastError
-getPrevError
-ping
-profile
-repairDatabase
-resetError
-whatsmyuri
-aggregate
-convertToCapped
-distinct
-findAndModify
-geoNear
-reIndex
-collStats
-dbStats